# Is there sample schema for carousel cards in Microsoft Bot Framework adaptive cards

Tags: adaptive-cards, botframework

I have tried to use the json provided in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#carousel-collection) and tried to insert in [Schema Explorer](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/)

But it does not render the card.

Comment: You can try this example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59684839/carousel-in-adaptive-card

Comment: Can you maybe provide some snippets from your actual code so we can see if there is something there that we might not be able to tell from looking at the sample documentation?

Comment: You can refer to this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/06.using-cards)